# Origem do componente DLTextBox

Tags: c#, windows-ce, smartdevice

Estou realizando um ajuste em um projeto em Windows CE, porem esse projeto teve seu código fonte perdido e o sistema passou por um processo de engenharia reversa.

Sabendo disso, comecei a pesquisar o tipo de projeto que era e cheguei aos projetos Smart Device do Visual Studio. E acabei de deparando com o seguinte componente:

```
private TabPage tabPagFunc;
private DLTextBox dlCodigo;
private Label lblFuncionario;
private TextBox txtFuncionario;
```

Fiz algumas pesquisar buscando esse "DLTextBox", porem não encontrei algo concreto que falasse de quem é o componente, se é do Visual Studio ou de Terceiros... Cheguei a achar algumas perguntas de fóruns com o objeto... Mas nada de saber sua origem. Poderiam me dizer de onde é o componente e caso seja de algum terceiro ou propriamente da Microsoft, aonde acho a documentação desse componente?

Obs: Acabei encontrando referências dentro de códigos em ASP, mas o projeto é para Windows CE.

Comment: Willian, ja trabalhei muito tempo com Windows CE e nunca vi esse componente, eu suspeito que ele seja um componente cutomizado, chegou a verificar nas DLLs se tem alguma DLL referente a esse componente? Imagino que você dá dando um Disassembly, olha nos usings se ele ta usando algo diferente.

Comment: É um componente da empresa DataLogic, disponível no  SDK do coletor Mermor X, sua aplicação é embarcada em algum dispositivo dessa linha?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo
Isso mesmo, é uma solução para Coletor da DataLogic, não sei qual o modelo... Depois de ler sua resposta fiz algumas pesquisas e não achei uma documentação sobre os componentes deles, sabe aonde posso conseguir?

Comment: O ideal seria você descobrir o modelo e entrar em contato com o suporte deles, pedindo o SDK